# typical way to run tails virtualized on ubuntu?

Tags: security, tails, ubuntu, encryption, virtual-machine

To run on Ubuntu just use KVM to run `tails`?

> If you are a bit lazy like me, the idea to reboot your system seems
>   inconvenient. But with the help of QEMU there is an easy to use
>   alternative available. QEMU is a program that allows us to emulate a
>   whole computer inside our running system. Running the Tails system
>   from inside QEMU has it’s drawbacks: If your host system is
>   compromised, so will you virtual machine. The other argument are the
>   traces you may leave behind: But with a full-disk encryption (or even
>   at least for your  home-partition), these can be almost mitigated.

https://fedoratips.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/run-tails-in-a-virtual-machine-for-anonymous-internet-access/

Answer (score 1):

Generally the virtualisation of choice is VirtualBox, see: [Tails VirtualBox documentation](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/virtualization/virtualbox/index.en.html)

However, also heed the warnings. Tails do not recommend using VirtualBox for day-to-day use. It's there mostly to help with testing.

> Running Tails inside a virtual machine has various security implications. Depending on the host operating system and your security needs, running Tails in a virtual machine might be dangerous.

It will lose its anti-forensic properties and it will only be as secure, private and anonymous as the host operating system.